# Classes in Classpath interfering with OSGi bundles

Tags: java, jasper-reports, osgi, classloader, apache-felix

I'm writing an OSGi bundle, let's call it B, that is to be deployed in an existing application. The bundle will need access to a library L (namely JasperReport), version V2.

Such library is in the classpath of the application, **not** as an OSGi bundle, but with version `V1 < V2`.

I tried two scenarios:

1. having a copy of the library's `L.jar` in my bundle's `B.jar`,
   and include it in the `Bundle-ClassPath`;
2. creating an OSGi-fied version `L-osgi.jar` of the library, with `bnd`, specifying in all the `Export-Package` that the  exported version is V2, deploying it along with my own bundle, and in the latter's `Import-Package` ask specifically for version V2.

I was expecting both of these methods to work, because I expect each bundle to only see the packages *specifically required* in an `Import-Package` header in the `MANIFEST`.

However, I get this error:

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Class net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry does not implement/extend net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsRegistry
```

which feels like it's using one copy of the library to get the base class/interface and another copy for the subclass (btw, it happens even if I bundlethe *same version* of the library).

I'll try to `Import-Package` the version of the library provided by the application, and make do with this older version, but why does this happen? Can I prevent it?

Comment: It should work the way you describe. I expect it's a packaging error. Where does your bundle B get the package `net.sf.jasperreports.extensions` from? Is it imported, or included in the bundle?

Comment: Imported in the second scenario, and included in the first one. Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: Hmm yes. There must be two copies of this API around and somehow interfering. Is it the same error message in both scenarios? Can you see which bundle is throwing the error? Providing the full stack trace might be useful.

Comment: The errors are back at the office, as is the stack trace, but unless I'm mistaken the error is the same, and it happens when the library is called by my bundle but not when it is called by the original application.

Comment: @kenshin - Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: @Pavan No. Rather, I somehow found a configuration option of the application that specifies additional packages from the classpath to be made available to OSGi bundles, and with than I can use directly the Jasper ilbrary already there.
But the question stands.